# Особенности произношения в начале XIX века

Tags: выбор-слов, история

Фраза "так что от 8 р. на 100 возвысился до 25 на 100" - рассуждения о брошюре г.Демидова и реформе денег в России в 19 веке. Как правильно писалось в 19 веке "8 р."? расшифруйте написание и произношение - рублей, рублёв или как-то ещё?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В XIX веке использовались обе формы: рублей и рублёв. В Нацкорпусе до 1800 года частотность 645:466, до 1900 года частотность 12000:872, до 1950 года 24000: 1060, после 1950 года 24500:400. (Правда, надо еще учитывать фамилию Рублёв).

Скорее всего, к середине XX века форма "рублёв" уже выходила из употребления, у Аванесова (1987 год) она вообще не упоминается. Сейчас "рублёв" можно встретить в   исторических романах, или эта форма имеет иронический подтекст, например: С тебя сто американских рублёв  (форум) (2005).

Примеры:

Да уж так; только вы, батюшка, Николай Кузьмич, ни в какую работу употреблять меня уж не извольте, а оброк положите, какой сами знаете». ― «Пятьдесят рублев в год! » ― «Извольте». [И. С. Тургенев. Хорь и Калиныч (1847)]

Напишу им: ежели будет ваша милость, пристегнете пять рублев, беспременно поеду. [М. А. Алданов. Истоки. Части 9-17 (1942-1946)] ..

Ставь триста рублев, товарищ Холодков, без всякого разговору. [П. С. Романов. Белая свинья (1931)]